# Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type long

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with this request, I did not understand it because I have another one using the long in the id and it is functional, but this returns this error whenever I try, really I do not understand much of Spring so this is difficult to solve.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/novopost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String savePost(@Valid Post post, @PathVariable("id") long id){
        post.setData(LocalDate.now());
        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findById(id);
        System.out.println(usuario);
        post.setUsuarios(usuario);
        System.out.println(post);
        postService.save(post);
        return "redirect:/time-line";
    }
```

> Error
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
> status=500). Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter
> of type long
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Missing URI
> template variable 'id' for method parameter of type long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `/{id}` in the url.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/novopost/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String savePost(@Valid Post post, @PathVariable("id") long id){
      post.setData(LocalDate.now());
      Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findById(id);
      System.out.println(usuario);
      post.setUsuarios(usuario);
      System.out.println(post);
      postService.save(post);
      return "redirect:/time-line";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it but also missing the (usuario.id) in HTML I did it and it was perfect.